# Why do we need to learn different Sorting algorithms when the STL sort function is already available to us in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl

Yesterday, this question came in my mind. Although I have neither read all the sorting algorithms like Quicksort, Merge Sort, Heapsort
Insertion Sort,
Selection Sort, and
Bubble Sort nor I have read the Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS but still, I am curious to know why there is a need to learn all such algorithms when the pre-defined sort function is already available to us in many languages.

Comment: Because engineering is all about tradeoffs. `std::sort` isn't the best sorting tool for every situation.

Comment: Because knowledge is power.

Comment: For that matter, why learn to program at all when there's so much software out there already made?

Comment: So that you can learn to program, instead of just cut and paste.

Comment: Sorting algorithms are an ideal testbed with which to learn how to analyse algorithms. You can work out worst case and average complexity easily for most of them (shell sort is tricky). You can work out an information-theoretic lower bound which you can pretty much meet (which is unusual). Timing Bubble sort vs Quicksort should give you an appreciation of the value of having an n log n algorithm instead of an n^2 algorithm, and of the fact that an algorithm such as Bubble sort, which appears sensible and straightforward, may not be optimal.

Comment: actually, you have `std::sort`, `std::stable_sort`, `std::partial_sort`, `std::partition`, and so on.

Comment: Contrary opinion: because your professor spent much time learning it, and believes it's still relevant. 95% of programmers don't need it. Software Engineering is **not** Computer Science, just like Applied Physics isn't Theoretical Physics.

Comment: The answer rather depends on what you mean by 'we' and 'need'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

1. Simply sorting only may not be always the requirement. The requirement can be different. You may need to modify / integrate a sorting algorithm in order to develop a completely different thing.
2. The predefined sorting methods may not be the efficient at all cases.
3. Its always not about the sorted result but the approach of sorting in order to improve time and space complexity. Efficiency is the key.
4. There is no particular algorithm that is guaranteed to work best at all cases. Pros and cons may differ for different algorithms.
5. Need to understand which algorithm to be applied at what scenarios.
6. Sorting may not always done with numbers. It can be applied on other different complex types / structures. (There may not be pre-defined methods for complex cases )
7. There is always scope for a better approach.

Comment: To be fair, `std::sort` can take a comparator to plug in complex sorting orders if the type doesn't have `operator<`.

Comment: Actually, the most important real-world engineering concern is where your data is stored, and that's completely ignored in the basic Comp.Sci treatment of sorting algorithms. In particular, Locality of Reference is a critical factor in sorting.